# Wheres does this PCB trace go?

Tags: pcb, soldering, repair, solder-mask

I am checking a damaged engine ECU. Two traces were damaged during opening of the ECU.

I put a circle around the damaged traces. I need help with the left trace.  Where does it connect to?

[image]

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding, green is copper, dark green is not conductive. So for me it is only one damaged track. You can solder a thin wire parallel, connected where the track ends in pads.

Comment: So thats one trace and the dark green lines are the edges?

Comment: Yes, there is a big pad at the bottom end and a much smaller one at the top end.

Comment: Scratch it very gently with a blunt knife or sharp screwdriver, and you'll reveal the copper and bare circuit board parts. In the area you're going to solder, try to keep the other (intact) tracks completely covered in green, so the solder doesn't stick to them too. Look for YouTube videos of PCB repair.

Comment: And make sure to "clean up" the damaged part and that there isn't a short between signal S and pour P1 or pour P2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpuTD.png

Comment: Optical magnification is your friend here!   Zoom way in on it, things will become more obvious to you.

Answer (score 1):

During PCB manufacturing, exposed copper traces/pours on the top and bottom layers are covered with what's called the *solder mask* - to protect them from solder during component assembly, as well as from general dirt/dust.

So what you are seeing here is light green = solder mask, dark green = non-conductive material of the layer below (ie fiberglass).

How to fix:

In this case you can see the entire, single trace on the picture. It goes between two pads and there's no vias. So the appropriate patch is to solder a thin, isolated wire between those two pads. Make sure the wire follow the board tightly pretty much at the same location as the broken trace. It should ideally not cross other pads. Secure it with hot glue, silicone or similar.

Also check the broken trace to ensure that no copper residue is shorting against other conductive areas of the PCB. You can remove such protruding copper remains with a small precision knife/scalpel.